# Extract strings based on pattern in python and writing them into pandas dataframe columns

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, pattern-matching

I have text data inside a caloumn of dataset as shown below

```
 Record    Note 1
  1       Amount: $43,385.23
          Mode: Air 
          LSP: Panalpina           
  2      Amount: $1,149.32
         Mode: Ocean  
         LSP: BDP
  3     Amount: $1,149.32
         LSP: BDP
         Mode: Road
  4     Amount: U$ 3,234.01
        Mode: Air   
  5     No details
```

I need to extract each of the details inside the text data and write them into new column as shown below how to do it in python

**Expected Output**

```
Record   Amount         Mode   LSP
1         $43,385.23    Air    Panalpina 
2         $1,149.32     Ocean  BDP
3         $1,149.32     Road   BDP
4         $3,234.01     Air       
5
```

Is this possible. how can this be do

Comment: Can you print `df.head().to_dict()` so we can re-create this example properly?

Comment: @ALollz, You can access sample test file from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nYbtult3nYNk5z0YYNwSWNa_Lc61yD_X

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom function and then use `pd.apply()` -

```
def parse_rec(x):
    note = x['Note']
    details = note.split('\n')
    x['Amount'] = None
    x['Mode'] = None
    x['LSP'] = None
    if len(details) > 1:
        for detail in details:
            if 'Amount' in detail:
                x['Amount'] = detail.split(':')[1].strip()
            if 'Mode' in detail:
                x['Mode'] = detail.split(':')[1].strip()
            if 'LSP' in detail:
                x['LSP'] = detail.split(':')[1].strip()
    return x

df = df.apply(parse_rec, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

Amount = []
Mode = []
LSP = []

def extract_info(txt):
    Amount_lst = re.findall(r"amounts?\s*:\s*(.*)", txt, re.I)
    Mode_lst = re.findall(r"Modes??\s*:\s*(.*)", txt, re.I)
    LSP_lst = re.findall(r"LSP\s*:\s*(.*)", txt, re.I)

    Amount.append(Amount_lst[0].strip() if Amount_lst else "No details")
    Mode.append(Mode_lst[0].strip() if Mode_lst else "No details")
    LSP.append(LSP_lst[0].strip() if LSP_lst else "No details")


df["Note"].apply(lambda x : extract_info(x))

df["Amount"] = Amount_lst
df["Mode"]= Mode_lst
df["LSP"]= LSP_lst

df = df[["Record","Amount","Mode","LSP"]]
```

By using regex we can extract information such as the above code and write down to separate columns.